# Many to Many relationship duplicates entry

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I have two entities linked by a many to many relationship. For the example, lets say my entities are DRIVER and CAR. A DRIVER can have multiple cars and a CAR can have multiple drivers.

On my DRIVER entity i've got :

```
/**
* @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="CARS")
* @ORM\JoinTable(name="driver_car")
protected $cars;
```

The name of the join table is fixed so I have to specify it.

When I save a new driver, I can specify multiple cars.

It works fine, I have my new driver saved in BDD, I have as many line in DRIVER_CAR as I have cars specified to my driver.

The problem is it creates new cars even though it already exist in CAR.

For example if I have 2 cars in DB, lets say :

### id | libelle

### 1 | Ferrari

### 2 | Porsh

Now I create a new driver named FOO and link him to a ferrari, I end up having :

### id | libelle

### 1 | Ferrari

### 2 | Porsh

### 3 | Ferrari

in DB.

FYI I use Symfony2 forms to save or update an entity.

I've tried to use different "cascade" values to no avail.
Can someone explain to me what I'm doing wrong please ?

Thank you for your time :).

Answer (score 0):

I've found where does my issue come from.

I'm using forms to validate my objects and it was poorly configured.

BEFORE :

```
            ->add('CARS', CollectionType::class, array(
            'entry_type' => CARSTYPE::class,
            'allow_add'  => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'by_reference' => false
        ))
```

AFTER:

```
    ->add('CARS', EntityType::class, array(
        'class' => 'CARS',
        'invalid_message' => 'Cannot find car.',
        'multiple' => true,
    ))
```